# Porting JDBCRealm from tomcat to OC4J

Tags: oracle, authentication, tomcat, authorization, oc4j

I'm porting a servlet from `Tomcat 5.5` to `OC4J 10.1.3.1`.

In Tomcat we set up a `JDBCRealm` for authentication and authorization.  This was configured via the `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`.

Is there a similar mechanism in `OC4J`?  Where do I start looking for it?  How do I define it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a similar mechanism in OC4J. It is the [DBTableOraDataSourceLoginModule](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28957/loginmod.htm#BABCDDAI) which is a login module that ships with OC4J.